# Are type aliases used as type of function parameter part of the function signature?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, alias, method-hiding

Consider an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <class, class T>
using alias = T;

template <template <class...> class>
struct tt_wrapper{};

template <class...>
struct t_wrapper{};

struct A {
    template <template <class...> class TT, class T>
    void foo(alias<tt_wrapper<TT>, T>) { std::cout << "A::foo invoked" << std::endl; }
};

struct B: A {
    using A::foo;
    template <class U, class T>
    void foo(alias<t_wrapper<U>, T>) { std::cout << "B::foo invoked" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    B b;
    b.foo<std::vector>(int{});
}
```

According to [[namespace.udecl]/15](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/namespace.udecl#15):

> When a using-declaration brings names from a base class into a derived
>   class scope, member functions and member function templates in the
>   derived class override and/or hide **member functions and member
>   function templates with the same name, parameter-type-list,
>   cv-qualification, and ref-qualifier (if any) in a base class (rather
>   than conflicting)**.

So apparently the template parameters should not be involved in member function hiding. However in our example the template parameters are brought to the signature using alias. Nevertheless [clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/OP9vZVN6H3bbNqCC) doesn't seem to share the feeling that alias is part of the function *parameter-type-list* and claiming:

```
prog.cc:26:7: error: no matching member function for call to 'foo'
    b.foo<std::vector>(int{});
    ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
prog.cc:21:10: note: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'U'
    void foo(alias<t_wrapper<U>, T>) { std::cout << "B::foo invoked" << std::endl; }
         ^
1 error generated.
```

I've intensionally omitted gcc in consideration as it involve template parameter list in the hiding process. Is clang right?

Comment: @StoryTeller I thought so too...

Comment: Yeah, I see. I'm still stuck in the days when this was conjoined with a "strong typedef" proposal.

Comment: I think this should be considered a Standard defect. Compare to the previous paragraph, which specifies for namespace scope function templates that the return type and template parameters do matter in determining whether a using-declaration makes the program ill-formed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A::foo` and `B::foo` has

- same name (`foo`)
- parameter-type-list (`T` !!!)
- cv-qualification (not `const`, not volatile)
- ref-qualifier (None)

template parameter list is not taken into account.

The method in base class is not virtual, so hiding and not overriding.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d5d3a50c024cb764) of the fact that the parameter-type-list is `T`.

Comment: So you're saying the alias have to be replaced with underlying type when considering in parameter-type-list, and the additional template argument of alias doesn't matter?

Comment: BTW, for [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/24a6188d15e36c3c), I don't know which compiler is right, if any.

Comment: yet another interesting [example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/oNUfAUaFhKEkI6Y0) this time using sfinae in first template alias argument... Does this really make the same signature?!

Comment: @W.F.: I would say they have same parameter-type-list, but SFINAE still applies at resolution.

Comment: OK but we can make the alias itself dependent parameter while still letting deduction of T, like [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/W4Ujo0tfoDjBvSL4). Have we just tricked the compiler/standard?